# Как победить Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемые профессионалы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/f/finman/site/public_html/sADM/index.php on line 256
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/f/finman/site/public_html/sADM/index.php on line 257*

В коде эти строки выглядят так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pg0 ORDER BY id;", $link); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Самое интересное, данный элемент прекрасно работал на 1 аккаунте хостинга, но при переносе на другой аккаунт этого же хостинга появились эти ошибки. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Ну судя по сообщению, надо посмотреть, как получается `$link`.

Comment: подключение к базе другое, отсюда и ошибка, проверьте логин пароль

Comment: Логин и пароль правильные. Иначе бы било ошибки. На это стоит тест. 
$ линк вот как получается:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pg0 WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."';", $link); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: если мне не изменяет память, то в mysql_query второй параметр $link (в вашем случае) необязателен, попробуйте без него. и уберите точку с запятой в конце запроса

Comment: Мм, мой вопрос был - откуда берётся `$link`. То есть `$link = ...`. Просто ошибка у вас о том, что в качестве `$link` у вас не resource соединение с БД, а какая-то непонятная штука.

Comment: В общем решил я проблему, только если мне кто-нибудь объяснит почему так работает, буду очень благодарен. сейчас опишу все в подробностях. Только проверю еще раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`", $link"` уберите, так как это не обязательный параметр, может, поможет.

Comment: да, помогает. Код начинает корректно исполняться. Но Вот честное слово я не понимаю почему. Как может $link работать у меня на хостинге, на моем компе и не работать на основном хостинге. З.ы. основной хостинг от того же хостераа что и мой. Тоесть вообще путаница. или просто моих скромных знаний не хватает что бы это понять.

Comment: Кривой $link!

Comment: =)) ооо, в моем вопросе появился спор)))) Жду объяснения, очень интересно почему так вышло! Спасибо, заранее.

Comment: @good ты на личности не переходи. И вообще за что ответ принял автор... я поражаюсь.

Comment: Я принял то, что сработало. Из того что предлагали - это первое что сработало и на привело к другим сбоям. Хотя, честно говоря я не понимаю каким образом это сработало. 1 и тот же код использую уже в 4 раз, но первый раз пришлось убирать хоть какой-то элемент. @Shrek  Давай дождемся его рассказа, может он на самом деле что-то прояснит. 
Потому-что я уже не знаю что думать... меня эти хостинги добьют скоро.

Comment: мне на код в взглянуть нужно

Comment: @Shrek, всё верно... И почему надо точку с запятой убрать? Она тут явно не при чём, кроме того она не делает запрос неверным. Всё дело исключительно в переменной `$link`. Как я понял, она была не определена, поэтому выходила ошибка. Её убрали - стал браться `resource`-соединение с БД по умолчанию и всё заработало.

Comment: @Kremchik объяснил бы мне кто почему оно работает в других случаях... а код я дать могу посмотреть может доработаем общими усилиями. Точнее не сам код, но то на основе чего я писал. http://www.php-adminka.ru/   вот на основе вот этой штуки я писал свою админку. Там все проверено и перепроверено, известная кстати админка для новичков. Очень простая и понятная. Единственный вопрос, который меня мучает - почему (проверил уже на 3 хостингах и на 4 аккаунтах) и только тут ЭТОТ ЧЕРТОВ глюк. Не люблю, когда не понимаю чего-то, поэтому и бьюсь.

Answer (score 4):

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pg0 ORDER BY id");  // не нужно ставить точку с запятой
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Ошибку в студию!

и прописать так

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pg0 ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: неа, именно в таком виде работало на предыдущем аккаунте. если убрать точку с запятой бьет другую ошибку.

Comment: @SKYnetRTX не путайте тчкзпт в запросе и в конце оператора :)

Comment: как не надо точку с запятой? WTF?

Comment: result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pg0 ORDER BY id;");

так тоже должно работать. учите матчасть ;)

Comment: И не просто должно, но и работает. Просто необязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри, что выдает mysql_error() и все поймешь!

Comment: var_dump юзал, mysql_error()  смотрел но так и не смог понять как и почему в 2 случаях из 3 работает, а в 3 нет. Там выше good обещал объяснить, вот жду этот интереснейший, для меня, рассказ.